# How to get value from array in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

The return function from the ` object looks like:

with `JSON.stringify`

```json
[
  {
    "Id": "**a6p5r000000LBxHAAW**",
    "Status": "a6o5r0000000EsVAAU",
    "Account": "AccountId"
  }
]
```

without `JSON.stringify`

```json
Proxy :
0 : Proxy
[[Handler]]: ut
membrane: bt.valueObserved {readOnlyObjectGraph: WeakMap, reactiveObjectGraph: WeakMap, valueMutated: ƒ, valueObserved: ƒ, valueIsObservable: ƒ, …}
**originalTarget** : {Id: '**a6p5r000000LBxHAAW**',,"Status":"a6o5r0000000EsVAAU","Account":"AccountId"}
```

I want to get the value of `Id` when *onclick button* :

```js
        handleGetFilters(response) {
            
            console.log('ASU in handleGetFilters');
            const { data } = response;
            if(data) {
                this.caseDefaultData = data.map((x,index)=>{
                        x = {...x,rowNumber:index+1};
                        console.log('x.Field__c****',x.Field__c);
                        console.log('ASU this.optionFields. ',JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.optionFields)))
                        let configField = this.optionFields.filter( options => options.Label === x.Field__c )[0];
                        console.log('XSOOSDSQDSQDQ****',configField);
                        console.log('ASU configField ',JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(configField)))
                        if(configField.Options__c != undefined) x.options = JSON.parse(configField.Options__c).data;
                        if(configField.Field_type__c === 'isLookup')  x.sObject = x.Field__c.includes('Compte') ? 'Account':'Contact';                
                         x[`${configField.Field_type__c}`] = true;
                return x;
               })
}
removeRow(event) {
  var ca = this.caseDefaultData.splice(event.target.dataset.index, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just `ca[0].Id`. The Proxy is a (mostly) transparent layer used for security purposes. Even though the `console.log` shows the `Proxy`, to running code, it is transparent.

Comment: but i dont want to get only the first one , i want to get list of ids

Comment: Then you can then do a map , or a for each
`let itemIds = ca.map(item => return item.Id)` Not a regular js writer but i guess this should sort it out

Comment: @Soji Close: `let itemIds = ca.map(item=>item.Id)`

Comment: @Soji with this approach , itemIds  contain only last id(element) deleted notall the deleted ids

Comment: @Farkous  oh i see then. do  it like this
`let itemIds = [];`
`ca.map(item => itemIds.add(item.Id));`
`console.log(itemIds);`

Comment: @Soji Map already returns an Array, you don't need items that way.

Comment: i have declared `itemIds` with *@track* because i need this array in other method and then : `this.itemIds = ca.map(item=>item.Id)` but it always return proxy empty ..  @soji with your approach i `itemIds` contains always last deleted id..

Comment: even with this approach  `var itemIds = [];
            ca.forEach(item  => itemIds.push(item.Id));
            console.log('ITEMSS',itemIds);`  the *itemIds* always contain last deleted id

Comment: any help guys?..

Comment: @Farkous You just need to keep a separate list if you want to remember all deleted rows, or you can compare to the original data if you have it stored somewhere.

Comment: Probably need a bit more context around what you're trying to achieve. Which goes beyond the above `Proxy` issue